# How to change X-axis data display interval in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have a large set of data, having more than 100,000 entries.

For example:

```
        Users
    1   2335
    2   2480
    3   2998
    4   450
    5   816
    .   .
    .   .
    .   .
    .   .
100000  621
```

I want to display a line chart.

The first column in the above data are the x-axis values and the second column (Users) are the y-axis values.

The chart that is getting displayed with these 100,000 rows is like this:
[image]

I don't want all the entries to be shown in graph, but instead I want to show data after specific intervals, to get something like this:
[image]

This image is a just a representation of how the graph should look like. The x-axis values should be integers as shown in example data above in first column.

How do I do this?

Comment: Your first graph has an integer x-axis.  Your second has time.  What is their relationship?  What have you tried?

Comment: In order to show data every X intervals, I believe you'll need to create a secondary data table to choose from.  You can format a chart to show the X-Axis *labels* every X intervals, but AFAIK you can't also hide that data at the same time, just by chart formatting.

Comment: If the x axes values and range are meant to be the same, and you are just trying to remove some number of points...have you considered adding a trendline with a rolling average?  With data that has that much noise in it, choosing the 100th point versus 101st could make for a big difference.  A rolling average will give a general sense of how things are improving or worsening over time.

Comment: @Adam the second graph is just a representation of how I want the graph to be. X-axis should have integer values.

Comment: @Adam Also, please can you tell how to add a trendline with rolling average as you said. I'm looking for intervals of 1000

Comment: @BruceWayne Please can you tell how to create a secondary data table using the original data? Suppose I have interval of 1000. What should be the formula?

Comment: The maximum interval in a moving average trendline is 255, so that won't work.  I agree with @BruceWayne that you will need (at least) a third column that contains exactly the data you want to plot.  So decide what it should be...do you want the nth point, the (1000+n)th point, the (2000+n)th point, etc?  Or a local average near each of those points?  Or a  1000-point rolling average?  When your data has that much chatter, it is a pretty important decision.